# Should I build for Silverlight 3 or Silverlight 4?

Tags: silverlight

I have a zip library (DotNetZip); currently the silverlight build is "unofficial" but I'm making it official.

Should I build for SL3 or SL4 or both?

Thanks for the input.

Comment: And why voting to close?  Seems appropriate to me. WTF?

Comment: I assume he is talking about his project and he wants to decide which silverlight version it should choose. If that is the case, then version should be 4.

Comment: Yes, "he" is talking about that.  But why 4?

Answer (score 1):

If you are releasing to the general public, consider releasing for both 3 and 4 (and 5 in a few months).

We still have to develop for Silverlight 3, for several clients, as their servers have not been updated to .Net 4 (required for some of the cooler server-side features of SL 4). Plesk based .Net hosting services also do not yet support .Net 4.